# Chop the Hydra in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I was working on a version of the problem that's here :  http://blog.gja.in/2014/01/functional-programming-101-with-haskell.html#.WIi0J7YrKHo

However if I were to give in an input of  chop chop [1,0,0,0], it should return [0,3,0,0]. I tried playing around with the code that was given on the above website however I can't seem to be figuring it out. I've also only started learning Haskell 3-4 days ago so I'm not sure what the right direction is to go on.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Don't just link to the page; include whatever context you need (but no more!) to explain the problem in the question itself.

Comment: `chop [1,0,0,0]` is for chopping off one 1st level head, which should result in `[0,0,0]` in the code as written.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the intended behavior. As rampion points out, 
`chop [1,0,0,0]` should result in `[0,0,0]`. I don't understand, where you get `[0,3,0,0]`, but I'll walk you through a little.

First, the definition of `chop`, with some comments that allow me to refer to each part of the definition.

```
chop []       = []                               --chopNull
chop (1:xs)   = xs                               --chopHead1
chop (n:xs) = (replicate (n - 1) (n - 1)) ++ xs  --chopHeadN
```

You asked about `chop chop [1,0,0,0]`. This isn't valid code. I'll assume you meant `chop (chop [1,0,0,0])`. Taking this as the starting point, I'll perform a bit of equational reasoning. That is, I'll transform the program fragment in question by substituting the relevant part of the definition. Each line has a comment indicating how the current line was calculated from the previous one.

```
chop (chop [1,0,0,0]) 
   = chop (chop (1:0:0:0:[]) --De-sugaring of List
   = chop (chop (1:xs))      --Let xs = 0:0:0:[] = [0,0,0]
   = chop (xs)               --chopHead1
   = chop (0:0:0:[])         --def of xs
   = (replicate (0 - 1) (0 - 1)) ++ (0:0:[])  --chopHeadN
   = [] ++ (0:0:[])          --From definition of replicate
   = (0:0:[])                --From defintion of (++)
   = [0,0]                   --re-sugaring
```

I do a few loose things above. Notably I equate `xs` to `(0:0:0:[])` in the comment. This is just to make it clear how that particular substitution is satisfied by the pattern match in the definition. Next, I used the `chopHeadN` definition to match the case where `n=0`, as it is the first thing that matches. You'll have to trust me on the definition of replicate and (++).

So that is what that particular call should be doing. Generally however, if you don't know what a particular function does, it is a good idea to start with some simpler input. For lists, an empty list `[]` or singleton's, `[n]` are good starting points. Then move on to two element lists. Like in this example, you can cut out part of a definition and inspect what that part does on known data. Do it yourself in ghci. (Actually, that's what I did for the replicate (0-1) (0-1) expression. I thought it would be an error.)